Load all subpartitions within a specific partition dynamically AWS athena present in s3
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE testpart
(id bigint,
eventday bigint,
eventhour bigint
PARTITIONED BY (eventday smallint,eventhour bigint)
ROW FORMAT SERDE'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' )

Suppose I have an Athena table with two column partitions as shown above.
on s3 i have s3/bucketName/eventday=1733941800000/eventhour=01
I want to load all partition under eventday,
which all eventhours under given eventday using alter statement like below.
ALTER TABLE testpart ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (eventday=1733941800000)

I have already gone through AWS Athena documentation but no luck.
I have also tried below query on Athena Query editor on AWS console but this is also did not worked.
ALTER TABLE testpart ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (eventday=1733941800000,eventhour=01)

I don't want to use MSCK REPAIR TABLE Command.
Any help appreciated Thanks in Advance.
